# Link on marker windows info

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a google map, I would to add a link on windows info of the markers.
The markers are generated from mysql database.

I tried to understand the code that I recovered but I can not add a link in the info window.

(You can not run the code)

```js
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('xml.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) { //loop
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');                    //stock id variable
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');                //stock name variable
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');           //stock address variable
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');                 //stock type variable
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(              //Recovered the coordinates for the markers 
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');         //Displays name in strong
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);

              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));     //Back to the line

              var text = document.createElement('text');            //Displays type
              text.textContent = type
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);

              var text = document.createElement('text');     //Displays id (Irrelevant)
              text.textContent = id
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);

              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); //Back to the line

              var text = document.createElement('text'); //Displays address 
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};  
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }
```

Photo of the result :

[Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jwCo.png)

I would like the text in strong, which displays the name to be a link to an url "bottle.php?id=" equal variable "id" which is already import

I hope I have expressed myself well, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution, here are the ones for a link:

```
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.textContent = "Visit this store"
          a.href = "/bottle.php?id=" + id;
          infowincontent.appendChild(a);
```